# Autofixture: Randomly fill property of a class

Tags: c#, autofixture

Concering the following class:

```
public partial class ByValueCondition 
{       
    public ParameterCondition ParameterCondition { get; set; }
    
    public TimeOfDayCondition TimeOfDayCondition { get; set; }
    
    public SimulationTimeCondition SimulationTimeCondition { get; set; }
    
    public StoryboardElementStateCondition StoryboardElementStateCondition { get; set; }
    
    public UserDefinedValueCondition UserDefinedValueCondition { get; set; }
    
    public TrafficSignalCondition TrafficSignalCondition { get; set; }
    
    public TrafficSignalControllerCondition TrafficSignalControllerCondition { get; set; }
}
```

I want a customization in autofixture that will randomly only choose one property and fill it, while leaving the other ones blank. The configuration of the underlying classes should be still defined by the global customizations of the fixture.

Also it should be possible to create a Collection of ByValueCondition.

I tried around with this but cant find an easy solution except creating a ISpecimenbuilder from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do it with following schema:

```
// Interface implemented by all Conditions
public interface ICondition
{
    bool IsConditionTrue(object ObjectThatWeKnow);
}

// Your object 
public partial class ByValueCondition 
{       
    public ICondition Condition { get; set; }
}

// And here you define all types of conditions
public class ParameterCondition : ICondition
{
    public object Parameter { get; set; }

    public bool IsConditionTrue(object ObjectThatWeKnow)
    {
        return ObjectThatWeKnow.Equals(Parameter);
    }
}

public class TimeOfDayCondition : ICondition
{
    public bool IsConditionTrue(object ObjectThatWeKnow) { return true; }
}

public class SimulationTimeCondition : ICondition
{
    public bool IsConditionTrue(object ObjectThatWeKnow) { return true; }
}
```

And the randomness you could do as:

```
var conditions = new List<ICondition>()
{
    new ParameterCondition() { Parameter = "whatever" },
    new ParameterCondition() { Parameter = "otherString" },
    new ParameterCondition() { Parameter = "NextOne" },

    new TimeOfDayCondition() { TimeBefore = DateTime.Now },
    new TimeOfDayCondition() { TimeAfter = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) },
}

var rand = new Random();
var randomN = rand.Next(0, conditions.Count);

var byValueCondition = new ByValueCondition();
byValueCondition.Condition = conditions[randomN]; //Here you assign random value
```